# What are Active Web Pages?

Tags: language-agnostic

I am not able to understand the difference between active and dynamic web pages.

I know that Active web pages are first downloaded on the client machine and then executed.
Dynamic web pages are executed on the server and then sent to the client.

But I am not able to correlate it with some real time example.

Kindly explain me the difference with some simple examples.

Also explain what is Applet and why it is active web page not dynamic.

Comment: Take some weeks to read several books & wikipages on [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), [HTML5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5), [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript), [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery). [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) could be a useful start (but is imperfect)

Comment: I don't think this active/dynamic distinction you make really exists. Certainly terminology I've not heard before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, **dynamic** is what's being executed on the server and then the result is being sent back to the client (browser). So for example when using PHP, your browser isn't able to execute PHP, so the *server* executes the PHP file and performs all logic in your code. The result will be an HTML file, which is then sent back to the client. The important thing to understand is that when the result is served to the client, the information in it won't change.

An **active** web page is a page where the *browser* performs the logic instead of the server. So for example when you've got a page where you're showing share prices, then you want it to update e.g. every 5 seconds. A solution would be to use AJAX with JavaScript. In contrast to PHP, your browser **is** able to execute JavaScript, so it is happening without reloading the page. So with an active page, everything is happening inside your browser without the need to reload the page every time you want new information.

An **applet** is an embedded application, like Flash or Java (not to be confused with JavaScript). To execute an applet, you most likely need a browser plugin. Because the applet is executed by the plugin and your browser, it is active and not dynamic (you don't need to request a new applet for information in it to change). The advantages of using an applet is that the programming language (like Java) has more possibilities than HTML. A lot of browser games are made with applets, but nowedays it is used less and less because we can achieve the same with techniques like JavaScript, HTML5 and WebGL.

Comment: When we enter our credentials, the mail box opens which is sent from the server. But we are able to manipulate it like deleting messages, or moving messages from one folder to another. As you said, "the information in it won't change" then how are we able to do that ?

Comment: Than it is a combination of dynamic (the initial mail box that's being sent to the browser) and active (using AJAX for example) to send requests to the server (like delete message x). When that action is successful, JavaScript will update the screen.

Comment: That means finally we are updating the dynaminc web page only since in future whenever we login we will get the modified mail box only.

Comment: Is it that the page will be the same but since we have updated the server database through that web page that's why it is showing the modified details ?

Comment: No, when the request to the server is successful, JavaScript (active) will modify the page, or request a partial of that page and replace it. When we reload the page, the updated result gets send back (dynamic)